# How do I add breaking points to my layout.xml?

Tags: layout, theme, rwd-theme, rwd

I want to remove a certain block on my website but only for desktop resolutions.
How do I add a breaking point to my `default.xml` inside my theme?

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this with css and your break points in there. If the page is loaded and the browser window is resized then your page won't displayed as expected. Depending on your css framework would depend how you do this. If you don't have a css framework then you can simply add in your own media queries